# Perl shared variables atomicity and visibility

Tags: java, multithreading, perl, visibility, atomic

This I read from the [`threads::shared`](http://perldoc.perl.org/threads/shared.html) description:

> By default, variables are private to each thread, and each newly created thread gets a private copy of each existing variable.  This module allows you to share variables across different threads ... [(more)](http://perldoc.perl.org/threads/shared.html#DESCRIPTION)

Let's say I have a shared variable like this:

```perl
my $var :shared;
$var = 10;
```

This means the variable exists only once for all the threads I create.

---

Now about atomicity and visibility:

If thread_A assigns a new value let's say 11:

```perl
$var = 11;
```

Is it guaranteed that thread_B (and all the other threads I might have created) will see the value 11 ?
And is the assignment performed atomically ?

Or do we have like in Java first to acquire a lock and then do the assignment and to release the lock. And only threads using the same lock are guaranteed to see the updated value?

Or this behaves like volatile primitive variables in Java ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's always good practice to enforce atomicity in updates. Perl provides [`lock`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/lock.html) to allow us to do this. You can `lock` the variable itself - if the variable is shared with the thread, then so is the lock state.

If you update `$var` then the other threads will see the new value.

But you do have a potential race condition, depending on when they access it. If that's a problem - `lock` and if it's not... carry on.

Bear in mind that operations such as `$var++` are not guaranteed to be atomic. (http://perldoc.perl.org/perlthrtut.html#Thread-Pitfalls%3a-Races)